# UI component custom column sorting not working

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent

I am creating 3 custom columns in sales order grid column:

1. Country
2. Area
3. City

Filters are working but when I try to sort the column it shows **`Attention: Something went wrong`**

> Iksula/InternationalShipping/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="country_id" class="Iksula\InternationalShipping\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Country">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="region" class="Iksula\InternationalShipping\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Area">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Area</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="city" class="Iksula\InternationalShipping\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\City">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">City</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> Iksula/InternationalShipping/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Country.php

```
<?php
namespace Iksula\InternationalShipping\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Country extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;


    public function __construct(ContextInterface $context, 
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, 
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, 
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria, 
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
        array $components = [], 
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $country_code = $order->getShippingAddress()->getData('country_id');
                $country = $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($country_code);
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $country->getName();
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

> Iksula/InternationalShipping/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Area.php

```
<?php
namespace Iksula\InternationalShipping\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Area extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;


    public function __construct(ContextInterface $context, UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria, array $components = [], array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $region= $order->getShippingAddress()->getData('region');
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $region;

            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

> Iksula/InternationalShipping/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/City.php

```
<?php
namespace Iksula\InternationalShipping\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class City extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;


    public function __construct(ContextInterface $context, UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria, array $components = [], array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $city= $order->getShippingAddress()->getData('city');
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $city;

            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your filters are not working. replace this

`<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>`

**By**

`<item name="filter" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>`

**and for sorting**

`<item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>`

This will solve your problem, pls mark it as solution if it works for you.

Comment: filter is working but sorting is not working

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: but this is not the solution to my question. I need filters and sorting to work

Answer (score 0):

Add Sort order to the column

`<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">40</item>`